# Ubuntu shifted theme and I am unable to change theme

Tags: icons, themes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWa2P.png)I have installed sweet-icon package. Icons and folders were colorful according to sweet style. Today, without inference (at least conscious), the theme changed. I have black-and-white theme and some mixture on the deck. (a printscreen included). Unable to change in tweaks. Tweeks icons fixed on sweet. Could anyone suggest me any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question?: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-contrast.html.en . it seems you have turned on high contrast.

Comment: Thanks my Friend...What else can I say...

Answer (score 3):

This looks as if you turned on the "High contrast" accessibility setting.

Head to "Settings", "Accessibility", and turn "High Contrast" off.

[image]

Comment: thanks vanadium. that's what i'm also trying to say.